# The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused when the configuration does not point to localhost

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am unable to connect to our Kubernetes cluster. The `kubectl` command does not seem to take the configuration into account...

When I issue a `kubectl cluster-info` (or `kubectl get pods`)
I get the following error message:

> The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

I was suspecting that the `~/.kube/config` was pointing to my minikube  but it is not the case:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: LS...==
    server: https://10.95.xx.yy:6443
  name: cluster.local
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: cluster.local
    namespace: xxx-cluster-xxx-xx-username
    user: username
  name: username-context
current-context: ""
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: username
  user:
    client-certificate: .certs/username.crt
    client-key: .certs/username.key
```

Surprisingly, the `$KUBECONFIG` environment variable is set to the correct path:

```
KUBECONFIG=/Users/username/.kube/config
```

and the `kubectl config view` works fine (a.k.a. is not pointing to `localhost` but to `https://10.95.xx.yy:6443`)

Finally, I also try to specify the path to the config file when invoking `kubectl` (`kubectl get pods --kubeconfig=/Users/username/.kube/config`), but the error remains the same...

Comment: Your current context is unset, as seen with `current-context: ""`; if you were to `kubectl --context username-context get pods` I would expect it to do more what you're expecting, and presuming I'm right, running `kubectl config set-context username-context` will fix it going forward

Comment: @mdaniel if you put your comment as an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current context is unset, as seen with `current-context: ""`; if you were to run `kubectl --context username-context get pods` I would expect it to do more what you want. If that turns out to be the case, one can run `kubectl config use-context username-context` to set the `current-context` going forward

Comment: Is there a way to not automatically try to connect? I don't always need it to connect whenever I open a new terminal window.

Comment: That sounds like a new question, please don't use comments for tech support

Comment: The placeholder suggests comments are for asking for more information. Not sure where the tech support part is. Thanks anyways.